# Telegram Bot - cant send photo from disc (bash script)

Tags: bash, telegram, telegram-bot

I got how to get photo from user

```
filepath=$(curl https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXX/getFile?file_id=$fileid | jq '.result.file_path' | sed 's/\"//g')

wget  https://api.telegram.org/file/botXXXXX/$filepath -P files/
```

I modify this photo and want to send it back, but i don't understand how POST works at all.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send a photo from your hard drive, you can do it with `curl`:

```
curl -F "chat_id=<RECIPIENT_CHAT_ID>" -F "photo=@/home/ivan/t_logo.png" \
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR_BOT_TOKEN>/sendphoto
```